# Image by user in gd library

Tags: php

Hey guys am creating a tool in which user is allowded to write the name and and when the user click the submit button he/she gets the image by his/her name..

## MY HTML CODE

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="images.php" method="post">
Enter image Name :<input type="text" name="imagename">
<br></br>
<input type="submit" name="sumbit">
<br></br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## MY PHP CODE

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");

$name = $_POST['imagename'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']) === true)
{
    $im = @imagecreate(800, 600)
}

else echo "no image created";


$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);

imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  "$name", $text_color);
imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);
```

When i run this code i get an error ..i need to generate the image only when user clicks submit button ..but i cant link my submit button to the php script ..Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: but when i add semicolon on imagecreate function the error gone but the image is not produced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `;` in `$im = @imagecreate(800, 600);`. Move your image generation code into `if` condition.

```
if($_POST['imagename'] != ''){
   header("Content-Type: image/png");
   $name = $_POST['imagename'];
   $im = imagecreate(800, 600);
   $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);
   $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);
   imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  "$name", $text_color);
   imagepng($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
}
else echo "no image created";
```

Comment: i fixed that ..but the image not produced ..when i ad semicolon

Comment: that didnt helped me ...it gives output no image created with a  Undefined index: imagename

Comment: Hey its working well in my local. Please check $_POST['imagename'] is set or not.